# SQL - Select NEW values after particular time (or id)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, time

I need an SQL in PHP for MySQL. Please view the table below:

```
 | id |       ip       |   time   |
 | -------------------------------|
 | 1    88.207.189.58  1321301482 |
 | 2    76.192.849.84  1321301487 |
 | 3    65.253.192.46  1321301492 |
 | 4    88.207.189.58  1321301522 |
 | 5    12.112.221.22  1321301582 |
 | 6    65.253.192.46  1321301633 |
 | 7    76.192.849.84  1321301657 |
 | 8    76.192.849.84  1321301710 |
 | 9    12.112.221.22  1321301819 |
```

I need to select the ip's that are NEW after a particular time

Eg: I want to select rows after time=1321301522 but they should be new, they may not appear before that time. In this case the only valid ip would be 12.112.221.22 (row 5).

This wouldn't work: **SELECT ip FROM table_name WHERE time>1321301522** because it would also list the non-new ones. They may not have appeared before that time.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT ip
FROM myTable
GROUP BY ip
HAVING MIN(time) >= 1321301522
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ip from tableName where time > 1321301522 and NOT EXISTS (SELECT ip from tableName where time <= 1321301522 )
```

Not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it is one way.

Comment: I'm gonna have to upvote Stuart's answer - much neater and leaner